# How to input a two names with space between them in java

Tags: java, string, input, output, spacing

I want to know how to input a name; Whereby the user will Type his **First name** and **last name** ***all at once***

```java
Scanner addressInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your name:");
        String name = addressInput.next();
```

I wanted the input format like so:
***Name(Space)secondName***

Comment: Try to read out the given String char by char and stop at your chosen separator, ' ' in this case. What would you do if someone´s name was "Mark Peter Smith" for example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to take input as String with spaces in java using scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514730/how-to-take-input-as-string-with-spaces-in-java-using-scanner)

Answer (score 1):

Use `addressInput.nextLine()` instead of `.next()`

Comment: @GitPhilter: scanner.nextLine() always triggers on pressing the enter key. There is no possibility to use .next() here, as it will always return, when space is pressed

Comment: Yes. I still think this has nothing to do with OP´s question. Say my name was Peter Smith, and I just by mistake type my name as "PeterSmith", than it doesnt fit OPs chosen format.

Comment: I think OPs problem was, that .next() already returned, when the user pressed space, so he had no possibility to enter his lastname. So .next does not work here. If he wants to ensure the user at least entered one space he should validate the string after.

Comment: Yeah, maybe it was, but let´s wait for what OP has to say. Maybe your solution is already the one OP was looking for, maybe not...:D